# Copy users to other database with the same permissions

Tags: sql-server, dbatools

We use dbatools to migrate/copy databases to other servers.
This sometimes means that we restore a database with a different name (ex: database => database_Test).

When I use the `Copy-DbaLogin` command, database permissions are only restored to the database if the name is the same.

I would like to know how I can copy logins/users and apply the permissions/rights to the renamed database.

Comment: Maybe I understand something wrong but if you copy an application database all users and user permissions still a part of it even if you rename it, so the only thing you need is to copy a login. Login and db user are linked via SID.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not super familiar with dbatools's process, but I imagine what's happening is you're creating [orphaned users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/troubleshoot-orphaned-users-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#resolve-an-orphaned-user) when you migrate the database.

If the Login already exists on the destination server, then all you need to do to resolve the orphaned users is run the following inside of the user database (the one you just migrated) where they are orphaned:

> ALTER USER TheUserName WITH Login = TheLoginName;

If the Login doesn't exist on that server yet, then you need to migrate it over, or use the following script in the `master` database to recreate it first, before running the aforementioned script:

> CREATE LOGIN TheLoginName
> WITH PASSWORD = 'TheLoginPassword',
> SID = TheLoginSID;